# sbt compile cycles loop indefinitely

Tags: windows, scala, shell, sbt

### versions

`Windows 10` 64bit

sbt `1.7.1`

scala `2.13.8`

### steps

- I updated sbt version from `1.3.13` to `1.7.1` in my project file `./project/build.properties`
- run command `sbt compile`, `sbt test` or `sbt run`

My **build.properties**:

```
sbt.version=1.7.1
```

### problem

With `1.3.13` version, when I changed some classes in my IDE (IntelliJ) then I launched my tests or commands like `sbt compile`, `sbt test` or `sbt run` all works fine and the process ends correctly.
Now, with `1.7.1` version, when I change some classes and launch the same commands then the process is endless and sbt compile indefinitively.

Log:

```
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: DefaultSessionService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 22 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: DefaultSessionService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 22 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: DefaultSessionService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 22 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: DefaultSessionService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 22 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\studio\tbg\project\session\DefaultSessionService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 22 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...

[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] C:\git\project\app\controllers\HomeController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] compiling 7 Scala sources and 15 Java sources to C:\git\project\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
```

### expectation

In `1.7.1` version, like in `1.3.13`, sbt should compile without any loop or cycle.

### notes

- I have tried with other sbt versions:

  - [✔️ ] 1.3.13
  - [✔️ ] 1.4.9
  - [✔️ ] 1.5.8
  - [❌ ] 1.6.2
  - [❌ ] 1.7.1
- Only with run `sbt clean` before `sbt test` all works fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried also running a `clean` and a `reload` before the `compile`? Maybe there is some weird cache.

Comment: Yep, I tried but after some class changes the issue returns.

Comment: Uhm, weird, I guess the best would be to try to create a MCVE and then open a bug report.